# Rails 4 - What is the best practice for restricting access to shared objects

Tags: permissions, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

User has_many Contracts as a Buyer
User has_many Contracts as a Seller

I know I can use CanCan to restrict a User to things they own.  But in this case I have a Contract that has both a Buyer & Seller.  I want the User to be able to see/read all Contracts for which they are the Buyer or the Seller.

I tried setting up a Scope and using it with CanCan but that doesn't seem to be working.

I setup my Ability as such...

```
can :read, Contract.parties(user.id)
```

My scope is defined as...

```
scope :parties, lambda { |user_id| where("seller_id = ? OR buyer_id = ?", user_id, user_id) }
```

I also tried setting up the abilities a different way...

```
can :read, Contract, buyer_id: user.id
can :read, Contract, seller_id: user.id
```

But the above seems to conflict and throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a block with CanCan abilities:

```
can :read, Contract do |c|
  (c.buyer_id == user.id) || (c.seller_id == user.id)
end
```

Comment: I didn't realize you could do that.  I'd give it a shot, but I've already swapped over to the protector gem.  I'll trust you and mark your answer as correct.

Comment: Thx. I'll check the protector gem as well, never heard of it.